# Avoid adding element to xml if no sub-properties end up being serialized?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a set of objects that I'm serializing to XML. These objects are bound together in a hierarchy, one object has many sub-objects in properties, and these in turn have sub-objects, etc.

If a property, containing an object, ends up being serialized as just `<tag />` because there was no properties to serialize in the object there (because they contain default values), then I'd like that tag to disappear as well, but I can't seem to find out if this is even possible, let alone how to do it.

I'll post a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program below, and this is what it dumps out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
  <child />
</root>
```

What I *want* it to dump out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root />
```

In other words, since the `child` tag ended up empty, I want it removed.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Note that I'm fully aware of adding a property with the name `XYZSpecified` of type Boolean, having it return `true` if the `XYZ` property is to be serialized, but since these objects will have many properties themselves, and contain many sub-objects that will also need to be checked, I'm basically asking if I can get the serializer to figure this out itself for me, by removing those tags from the XML because they was empty.

Can I change the `XmlElementAttribute` attributes in some way to accomplish this? Or do I really have to go the route of adding `XYZSpecified` properties with all the entailing logic to check if the object contains anything that will result in it being serialized?

Here's the [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program:

```
void Main()
{
    var root = new Root();
    root.Child = new Child();

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
    var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, root, ns);
        writer.ToString().Dump();
    }
}

[XmlType("root")]
public class Root
{
//    [XmlIgnore]
//    public bool ChildSpecified { get { return Child != null && Child.HasValues; } }

    [XmlElement("child")]
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
//    [XmlIgnore]
//    public bool HasValues { get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name); } }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The commented out code can be added back to the program, and then it accomplishes what I want, but seeing as the Child object will have many properties in the actual project, and some of those properties will contain objects with properties themselves, this looks like a maintenance nightmare and a recipe for bugs. If the XML serializer can be persuaded to figure out this by itself, then that would be better.

Comment: AFAIK, the `*Specified` or `ShouldSerialize*()` routes are the only options here. Personally I tend to prefer the latter, as methods (unlike properties) don't accidentally show up in other contexts (data-binding, etc).

Comment: I did not know about `ShouldSerialize*()`, thanks for that information.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like already answered by  Marc Gravell. 
Just make serialization conditional, using  ShouldSerialize*

```
[XmlType("root")]
public class Root
{
    //    [XmlIgnore]
    //    public bool ChildSpecified { get { return Child != null && Child.HasValues; }   }
    Child c;
    [XmlElement("child")]
    public Child Child { get { return c; } set { c = value; } }

    public bool ShouldSerializeChild()
    {
        return c.Name  != null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you read the complete question? The question is how to avoid doing just that.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Good question, and I like you feel "ShouldSerialize" is a bit of a clunky way to have to do this, but unfortunately sometimes the answer is that you can't do it any other way.